# Метод init и множественное наследование python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть два класса которые наследуются третьим. Не видит инит второго класса

```
class Sellary(object):
    """Sellary Class """

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def get_sellary(self):
        return "{}$".format(self.value)

class User(object):
    """ USER CLASS """

    def __init__(self, name, sername):
        self.name = name
        self.sername = sername

    def __repr__(self):
        return "This is {} {}".format(self.name, self.sername)



class Developer(User, Sellary):
    """ THis is a Developer Class who extends User, Sellary"""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "hello I'm a Developer {} {}".format(self.name, self.sername, self.get_sellary())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    John = Developer('John', 'Doe', value=10000)
    print(John)
```

Последний аргумент value не присваивается, подскажите как этим пользоваться)
`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'value'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В ответе @AndrioSkur синтаксическая ошибка. Вызывать инициализаторы действительно надо явно, но вызов будет иметь такой вид.

```
class Developer(User, Sellary):
    def __init__(self, name, sername, value):
        Sellary.__init__(self, value)
        User.__init__(self, name, sername)
```

Answer (score 2):

init по умолчанию узнаеться через MRO(то есть с левого класса). Если вам надо 2 init вызывает их явно.

```
__init__(self, name, surname, value):
     super(User, self).__init__(name, surname)
     super(Sellary, self).__init__(value)
```

Хотя воообще говоря, я не уверен в корректности такого подхода...

Comment: Если вы уже знаете имена классов-предков, нет нужды в их определени через super. Предпочитаю вызвать явно User.__init__(self, name, surname)

Comment: А вы пробовали это запустить? У вас ошибок не появилось?

Comment: `TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/890392/revisions в последней ревизии есть точно такой же код вызова super. А я не знаю точно мб автор ошибся с версией питона в метке, и в действительности пишет на питоне 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Тема не новая, но правильный ответ так и не появился.
Может я и не дока, но мой вариант хотя бы рабочий:

```
class Square:
    def __init__(self, edge_length):
        self._edge_length = edge_length


class Triangle:
    def __init__(self, tri_base, tri_height):
        self._tri_base = tri_base
        self._tri_height = tri_height


class Pyramid(Square, Triangle):
    def __init__(self, edge_length, tri_base, tri_height):
        Square.__init__(self, edge_length)
        Triangle.__init__(self, tri_base, tri_height)
```

Python 3 все работает ошибок не появилось.
Вообще строго говоря тут такой вариант уже был, но почему-то не зашел!
Я намеренно не стал править исходный код про Develop'ера.

Comment: "Тема не новая, но правильный ответ так и не появился."  "Вообще строго говоря тут такой вариант уже был, но почему-то не зашел!" - так был правильный ответ или не был? Вы определитесь, а то одно предложение противоречит другому.

Comment: Правильный вариант БЫЛ, но я написал так чтобы можно было номально разобраться как наследовать 2 класса (или более) и что делать с их атрибутами.